# How could I quit a C++ blocking queue?

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue

After reading some other articles, I got to know that I could implement a c++ blocking queue like this:

```
template<typename T>
class BlockingQueue {
public:
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::condition_variable not_full;
    std::condition_variable not_empty;
    std::queue<T> queue;
    size_t capacity{5};

    BlockingQueue()=default;
    BlockingQueue(int cap):capacity(cap) {}
    BlockingQueue(const BlockingQueue&)=delete;
    BlockingQueue& operator=(const BlockingQueue&)=delete;

    void push(const T& data) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        while (queue.size() >= capacity) {
            not_full.wait(lock, [&]{return queue.size() < capacity;});
        }
        queue.push(data);
        not_empty.notify_all();
    }

    T pop() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        while (queue.empty()) {
            not_empty.wait(lock, [&]{return !queue.empty();});
        }
        T res = queue.front();
        queue.pop();
        not_full.notify_all();
        return res;
    }

    bool empty() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        return queue.empty();
    }

    size_t size() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        return queue.size();
    }

    void set_capacity(const size_t capacity) {
        this->capacity = (capacity > 0 ? capacity : 10);
    }
};
```

This works for me, but I do not know how could I shut it down if I start it in the background thread:

```
void main() {
    BlockingQueue<float> q;
    bool stop{false};
    auto fun = [&] {
        std::cout << "before entering loop\n";
        while (!stop) {
            q.push(1);
        }
        std::cout << "after entering loop\n";
    };
    std::thread t_bg(fun);
    t_bg.detach();
    // Some other tasks here
    stop = true;
    // How could I shut it down before quit here, or could I simply let the operation system do that when the whole program is over?
}
```

The problem is that when I want to shut down the background thread, the background thread might have been sleeping because the  queue is full and the push operation is blocked. How could I stop it when I want the background thread to stop ?

Comment: Add flag variables that you use in both the loop condition and inside the lambda to check for exit?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Hi, would make it clear or add an answer with some sample code?

Comment: check [jthread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way would be to add a flag that you set from outside when you want to abort a `pop()` operation that's already blocked. And then you'd have to decide what an aborted `pop()` is going to return. One way is for it to throw an exception, another would be to return an `std::optional<T>`. Here's the first method (I'll only write the changed parts.)

Add this type wherever you think is appropriate:

```
struct AbortedPopException {};
```

Add this to your class fields:

```
mutable std::atomic<bool> abort_flag = false;
```

Also add this method:

```
void abort () const {
    abort_flag = true;
}
```

Change the `while` loop in the `pop()` method like this: (you don't need the `while` at all, since I believe the condition variable `wait()` method that accepts a lambda does *not* wake up/return spuriously; i.e. the loop is inside the wait already.)

```
    not_empty.wait(lock, [this]{return !queue.empty() || abort_flag;});

    if (abort_flag)
        throw AbortedPopException{};
```

That's it (I believe.)

In your `main()`, when you want to shut the "consumer" down you can call `abort()` on your queue. But you'll have to handle the thrown exception there as well. It's your "exit" signal, basically.

Some side notes:

1. Don't detach from threads! Specially here where AFAICT there is no reason for it (and some actual danger too.) Just signal them to exit (in any manner appropriate) and `join()` them.
2. Your `stop` flag should be atomic. You read from it in your background thread and write to it from your main thread, and those can (and in fact do) overlap in time, so... data race!
3. I don't understand why you have a "full" state and "capacity" in your queue. Think about whether they are necessary.

**UPDATE 1**: In response to OP's comment about detaching... Here's what happens in your main thread:

1. You spawn the "producer" thread (i.e. the one that pushed stuff onto the queue)
2. Then you do all the work you want to do (e.g. consuming the stuff on the queue)
3. Sometime, perhaps at the end of `main()`, you signal the thread to stop (e.g. by setting `stop` flag to `true`)
4. then, and only then you `join()` with the thread.

It is true that your main thread will block while it is waiting for the thread to pick up the "stop" signal, exit its loop, and return from its thread function, but that's a very very short wait. And you have nothing else to do. More importantly, you'll know that your thread exited cleanly and predictably, and from that point on, you know definitely that that thread won't be running (not important for you here, but could be critical for some other threaded task.)

That is the pattern that you usually want to follow in spawning worker thread that loop over a short task.

**Update 2**: About "full" and "capacity" of the queue. That's fine. It's certainly your decision. No problem with that.

**Update 3**: About "throwing" vs. returning an "empty" object to signal an aborted "blocking `pop()`". I don't think there is anything wrong with throwing like that; specially since it is very very rare (just happens once at the end of the operation of the producer/consumer.) However, if all `T` types that you want to store in your `Queue` have an "invalid" or "empty" state, then you certainly can use that. But throwing is more general, if more "icky" to some people.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. If I do not use detach(), my main thread would block at the `join()` function and I cannot deal with other task in the main thread, don't I? Besides, I added the `full()` and `capacity` because the object that I pushed into the blocking queue is very large and I do not want memory overflow.

Comment: Also, will it be ok if I return an empty object by `pop()` if `abort_flag==true` is detected ? It seems that the usage of throw is not recommended ?